# Как вывести все строки из таблицы excel в Telegram бот

Tags: python, telebot, excel, бот

Сижу думаю как вывести "range", то есть все строки, в одном сообщении бота (lib telebot). Help Please!

p.s. Бот выдаёт только одну строку в сообщении. Хотя в консоли, при выводе через print все данные отображаются как надо.

```
import openpyxl

book = openpyxl.open(f'skins.xlsx', read_only=True)

sheet = book.active


for row in range(1, 4):
    name = sheet[row][0].value
    price = sheet[row][1].value
    result = {f'*{name}* - *{price}*₽\n\n'}
```

Comment: Не знаю, что там у вас за бот, но советую большой объём сохранять в текстовый файл и потом его передавать. Сам такое сделал недавно

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно записывать каждый row в список и уже этот список передавать боту для отправки сообщения

```
import openpyxl
book = openpyxl.open(f'skins.xlsx', read_only=True)
sheet = book.active
message = []
for row in range(1, 4):
    name = sheet[row][0].value
    price = sheet[row][1].value
    result = {f'*{name}* - *{price}*₽\n\n'}
    message.append(result)
```